# How to get gnuplot label value?

Tags: label, gnuplot

I'm adding labels to a plot. I've followed this [tutorial for moving label to best position](http://www.gnuplotting.org/interactive-label-placing/) with the mouse and was glad to discover label can be rewritten at mouse position.

But once it's done, I haven't found any way to get the text value of the label if one wants to move the label at a later time (if in need to adjust position more accurately when zooming say) without copying/pasting the label's text.

In the script, the text is entered and kept around, but I would like to move the label with its id only and get the text or any other way to move the label.

```
gnuplot> set label 1 "square" at 0,0
> show label
 label 1 "square" at (0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000)
> moveLabel(labelId, text) = sprintf('call "label_loop.gnu" "%s" "%d"', text, labelId)
> eval moveLabel(1, "square") -> should be: eval moveLabel(1)
```

'label_loop.gnu' for gnuplot-5.0 is [the comment part](http://www.gnuplotting.org/interactive-label-placing/#comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention that you want to call the function just as `eval moveLabel(1)`, I assume that the label has been previously set within your script using `set label ...`. If this is the case, you could modify `label_loop.gnu` as:

```
#make sure that label_number is an integer and not a string so that
#it is not "misinterpreted" in "set label"
label_number = int(ARG1);

pause mouse any "adjust label"

#any other button will quit the loop
if( MOUSE_BUTTON == 1 ) {

    #using ARG1 instead of label_number or int(ARG1) would
    #create a new label with the content of ARG1 as its text
    set label label_number at MOUSE_X,MOUSE_Y 

    print "\n moved label ".ARG1." to position: ",MOUSE_X,MOUSE_Y
    replot
    call 'label_loop.gnu' ARG1
}
```

and then use it from the main script for example as:

```
set term x11
set mouse

set label 1 "square" at 0,0
moveLabel(labelId) = sprintf('call "label_loop.gnu" "%d"', labelId)

plot x

eval moveLabel(1)
```

The "trick" here is that if you call the `set label` command without any text, Gnuplot just updates the position and keeps the text as it was...

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know I could only use "set label {<tag>} " without "<label text>". I guess we can't get the text from the label Id as was my first idea.